# Handle home key press in lockscreen type application

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-homebutton

I'm taking lots of inspiration from app **Go Locker** and project [LockScreenApp](https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp), to create a basic lockscreen app that displays various pictures, randomly picked from a folder on device storage. App is working fine. My event receiver receives `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` event properly, kicking off my `Activity`, which is visible on front when screen is switched back on. I can swipe on my view to "unlock", works fine. So far so good.

Next step is to handle home `Button`. Now I know that `onAttachedToWindow()` of handling home `Button` press doesn't work with 4.X. I'm working with S2 (4.1.2).

Although, it definitely seem possible, as **Go Locker** does this (on the same device) flawlessly, without a single blink on the screen.

Initially I thought setting my app as default launcher might resolve this, but **Go Locker** doesn't do that. I can successfully continue using my **Nova Launcher** as my default launcher, yet **Go Locker** lockscreen successfully intercepts HOME key press and keep me on the lockscreen.

I tried intercepting `onPause()` & `onStop events on my`Activity`, and kicking off another instance of my`Activity` from there, but it doesn't work that way.

**Go Locker** seems to be doing something cleverer than that. Any idea how this can be achieved please?

Comment: Do you have a repo to share? I'm found the same problem over the internet but not a clue on how to solve... i'm thinking in try to replace the Keyguard Service, but i don't know if this approach will do the job.

Comment: By any chance did yo resolve this issue. I am struggling for almost a week to resolve this. There are many apps like SmartAppLock handling this flawlessly. Please advise if this issue is resolved for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not resolved :(